# How to substitute multiple line feed with a single line feed

Tags: excel, vba

I have this data in a single cell wrapped.

```
This
is



a




bad dream
```

For my report formatting purpose, i need to reduce multiple line feeds. Whenever there are more than 2 line feeds between 2 strings, they need to be replaced by exactly 2 line feed. So the data must look like

```
This
is

a

bad dream
```

I'm just a beginner in excel scripting. I tried using the substitute function but couldn't get the right result.

Can some looping be done using substitute?

Answer (score 3):

> Whenever there are more than 2 line feeds between 2 strings, they need to be replaced by exactly 2 line feed.

Use this small function:

```
Function customSubstitute(myStr As String) As String
    customSubstitute = myStr
    Do While InStr(1, customSubstitute, Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Chr(10))
        customSubstitute = Replace(customSubstitute, Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Chr(10), Chr(10) & Chr(10))
    Loop
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks simoco. That worked perfectly fine. I used the below code. A bit of extra coding than required, i guess.  Sub removeempty()
Dim str As String, n As Long, a As Long
Dim line2 As String, line3 As String
str = Range("A1").Value
a = Len(str)
line2 = Chr(10) & Chr(10)
line3 = Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Chr(10)
For n = 1 To a
 If Mid(str, n, 3) = line3 Then
 str = Application.Substitute(str, Mid(str, n, 3), line2)
 MsgBox str
 End If
Next n
 
Range("C1").Value = str
End Sub

Comment: edit your question with this code, since it's unreadable in comments